Lower bounds for the expectation of log ratio between the posterior and prior Beta densities
The quantity I'm interested in is expressed as follows:
$$
I = \mathbb{E}_{k\sim \text{Binom}(n,p)} \left[\ln \frac{\text{Beta}(p;a+k,b+n-k)}{\text{Beta}(p;a,b)}\right]
$$
The term inside the expectation can be interpreted as the log ratio between the posterior and the prior of the Beta distribution evaluated at $p$ after observing $n$ Bernoulli($p$) coin flips with $k$ heads. As $n$ grows, I suspect that this expectation should grow no slower than $\ln(n)$ regardless of the choice for $a,b>0$ and $p\in[0,1]$. In short, I want to show that $I=\Omega(\ln(n))$.
My attempt
Recall the p.d.f of the Beta distribution at $p$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Beta}(p;a,b)&=p^{a-1}(1-p)^{b-1} B(a,b)^{-1}\\
&=p^{a-1}(1-p)^{b-1} \frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}
\end{align}
$$
We rewrite the quantity of interest $I$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \mathbb{E}_{k\sim \text{Binom}(n,p)} \left[\ln \frac{p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\Gamma(a+b+n)\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+k)\Gamma(b+n-k)\Gamma(a+b)}\right]\\
&= np\ln(p)+n(1-p)\ln(1-p) + \mathbb{E}_{k\sim \text{Binom}(n,p)} \left[\ln \frac{\Gamma(a+b+n)\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+k)\Gamma(b+n-k)\Gamma(a+b)}\right]
\end{align}
$$
At this point, I'm not sure how to move forward with the expectation of the Gamma terms.

Are $a,b,p$ fixed?

@IosifPinelis Yes they are fixed parameters.

Your conjecture is true.
Indeed, by Stirling's formula with an error bound for the gamma function,
\begin{equation*}
    I\ge J-C; \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
here and in what follows, $C$ stands for various positive real numbers (possibly different even within one expression) depending only on $a,b,p$ and
\begin{equation*}
    J:=\frac12\ln n
    + n\big(h(p)+h(1-p)\big) \\
    -nE\big(h(p_n+a/n) +h(1-p_n+b/n)\big)+\frac12 Er_n , \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
where $h(u):=u\ln u$ for $u>0$ (with $h(0):=0$), $np_n$ is a random variable with the binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$, and
\begin{equation*}
    r_n:=\ln\frac{(p_n+a/n)(1-p_n+b/n)}{2(1+(a+b)/n)}. 
\end{equation*}
Also,
\begin{equation*}
    r_n\ge\ln\frac{\min(a,b)/n}{2(1+(a+b)/n)}\ge-\ln n-C.
\end{equation*}
Let $t:=\min(p,1-p)/2$. By Chebyshev's inequality,
\begin{equation*}
    P(|p_n-p|\ge t)\le\frac1{nt^2}. \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    Er_n\,1(|p_n-p|\ge t)\ge-\frac{\ln n+C}{nt^2}\ge-C. \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
Next, if $|p_n-p|<t$, then $r_n\ge\ln\frac{t(1-t)}{2(1+(a+b)/n)}\ge-C$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    Er_n\,1(|p_n-p|<t)\ge-C. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    Er_n\ge-C. \tag{50}\label{50}
\end{equation*}
Using again \eqref{30} and noting that $0\le p_n\le1$ and that the function $h$ is locally bounded, similarly to \eqref{40} we conclude that
\begin{equation*}
    nE\big(h(p_n+a/n)+h(1-p_n+b/n)\big)\,1(|p_n-p|\ge t) \\ 
    \le nC E1(|p_n-p|\ge t)\le C. \tag{60}\label{60}
\end{equation*}
Next, because $h<0$ on $(0,1)$ and $h''$ is locally bounded on $(0,1)$, and using \eqref{30} once again, we have
\begin{align*}
&   nEh(p_n+a/n)\,1(|p_n-p|<t) \\ 
&   \le nE[h(p)+(p_n+a/n-p)h'(p)+C(p_n+a/n-p)^2]\,1(|p_n-p|<t) \\       
&   \le n[h(p)+|h(p)|E1(|p_n-p|\ge t)+E(p_n+a/n-p)h'(p) \\ 
&\qquad +C|h'(p)|\,E1(|p_n-p|\ge t)
+CE(p_n+a/n-p)^2] \\    
&\le nh(p)+C. \tag{70}\label{70}
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
nEh(1-p_n+b/n)\,1(|p_n-p|<t) \le nh(1-p)+C. \tag{80}\label{80}
\end{align*}
Collecting now \eqref{10}, \eqref{20}, \eqref{50}, \eqref{60}, \eqref{70}, and \eqref{80}, we get
\begin{equation}
    I\ge\frac12\ln n-C.\quad\Box
\end{equation}

In fact, following the lines of the proof, one can see that
\begin{equation}
    \Big|I-\frac12\ln n\Big|\le C.
\end{equation}

Thanks a lot for your efforts! Is there any intuitions/motivations for using concentration bounds (Chebyshev's) here? Seems like a nice trick in general.

@entropy07 : If we replace $p_n$ by $p$ in (20), then it is easy to see that the resulting expression is $\frac12,\ln n+O(1)$. Also, the relative frequency $p_n$ is close for large $n$ to the probability $p$. So, it is natural to use some bounds on that closeness.

Can you explain the steps in $(60)$ and $(70)$? I guess I don't fully understand the two cases and why you used Taylor's expansion for the second case.

Also, inequality $(40)$ doesn't seem to hold when when $n$ is small. And is it true that $C\geq0$ always?

@entropy07 : (i) I have provided details on (60) and (70). For some of those details (in contrast with what was before), we do need to assume that $C\ge0$. Note also the added clarification "(possibly different even within one expression)" concerning the use of the symbol $C$. The Taylor expansion is used in (70) because it works. For (60), where a very different expression is bounded, such an expansion is not needed.
(ii) (40) holds for all $n\ge1$, because $\ln n\le n-1$ for such $n$.

Thank you for the clarification; this helps clear up some of my previous doubts. However, I still have one concern: don’t we need to find an upper bound for $nE\big(h(p_n + a/n) + h(1 - p_n + b/n)\big)$ since there is a negative sign in front of it in (20)? Apologize in advance if I missed something.

@entropy07 : Thank your comment. This is now fixed.
